# Subfolders in SparkJava's static files folder not mapped

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm doing a GUI in Angular which is calling a REST-api written in SparkJava (JavaSE). Everything will be running on the same machine.
The GUI was originally written in swing but I'm rewriting it in Angular to get a more modern touch.

**Problem:**

When the application starts everything seems to be loaded as expected. When I open the web page in a browser I get an INFO-message in the Java-console stating `spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/sv/assets/images/image1.png] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [image/webp,*/*]`, among other similar messages.

The Angular files are located in `src/main/resources/public`. There are a few subfolders with content, see screen shot.

The backend is served as it should, but the frontend files can't be loaded properly in the browser. HTML/JS/CSS seems to be loaded correct, but images and other files in `assets` folder can't be loaded.

Can this be solved? Or do I have to put all files in the root directory? I found nowhere all static files in SparkJava have to be located in the same folder (meaning, no subfolders).

**My setup:**

```
Spark.port(4567);
Spark.staticFiles.location("/public");

// simple rest API to serve some data
Spark.get("/labels/getall", "application/json", new Route() {
  @Override
  public Object handle(Request rqst, spark.Response rspns) throws Exception {
    Labels l = LabelReader.getLabels();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(l);
  }
});
```

**File tree:**

[image: File tree]

**Java console messages**
[image: Java console messages]

**Browser output**

[image: Browser output]